# Discontinuous in every point function

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a discontinuous function at all points except $(0, 0)$, $f(x, y)$, for which for any $x_0, y_0$ functions $f(x_0, y)$ and $f(x, y_0)$ are non-constant?

Answer (score 1):

How about $$f(x,y)=\begin {cases} (x,y)& x,y \text { rational}\\
(x,-y) & x\text { rational},y \text { irrational}\\
(-x,y) & x\text { irrational},y \text { rational}\\
(-x,-y)& x,y \text{ irrational}\end {cases}$$